# How to get rid of "undefined" text when jqGrid is initially loaded

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid on a page and whenever I load the page the jqGrid at first shows "undefined" and then loads the data about a half a second later(Depending on network latency). My question is how do I get this to say something like "loading" or something other than "undefined"? I notice the jqGrid examples don't have this problem and do say "loading" but I don't understand what makes them work and mine not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This grid should never say "undefined" during loading.

Are you using a custom i18n file that may not have "Loading" defined? Failing that, please post your code - or a working example - so we can have a look at your specific issue.

Also, what version of jqGrid are you using?

Comment: Ah, the i18n file. I forgot to link it in!

Comment: That would do it! I'm glad you tracked it down :)